# Possibilities for a group $G$ that acts faithfully on a set of objects with two orbits?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> A group $G$ acts faithfully on a set $X$ of 5 objects. The action has
>   two orbits: one of size 2, and one of size 3. What are the
>   possibilities for the group $G$?

I think I should apply the orbit-stabilizer theorem. I believe a main hint is the fact that this group has precisely two orbits but I'm not sure how to use that information. What's a good way to go about listing the possibilities for this group $G$?

Comment: As a hint, assuming that the two orbits are specified as $\{1,2\}$ and $\{3,4,5\}$, here are just three possibilities for $G$, two of order $6$ and one of order $12$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First determine the order of the group. Remember that it is a subgroup of $S_{5}$. The size of an orbit must divide the size of the group, which in turn must divide the order of $S_{5}$; so this means that $|G|$ is a multiple of $6$ which also divides $120$.

On the surface that looks like there are a lot of options, but consider that any $\sigma \in G$ can be decomposed into its' action on each orbit, so really you can consider $G$ a subgroup of $S_{2} \times S_{3}$, which has order $2\cdot 6 = 12$. Notice this also means you can describe the possibilities for $G$ by classifying the transitive subgroups of $S_{2}$ and $S_{3}$.

**[EDIT]** My hint really only makes two of the three possibilities apparent, namely $\mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{3}$ (order 6) and $\mathbb{Z}_{2} \times S_{3}$ (order 12). But as noted by Derek Holt, there is actually a third possibility, namely a second group of order 6. I would suggest to consider how $G = S_{3}$ can act on the orbits $\{1,2\}$ and $\{3,4,5\}$ in an appropriate way, by considering the action of the two generators of the group (i.e. consider $S_{3} = \langle \alpha, \beta \mid \alpha^{3} = \beta^{2} = e,\ \beta \alpha \beta = \alpha^{-1} \rangle$).

Comment: I don't think it's really right to say that you "can describe the possibilities for $G$ by classifying the transitive subgroups of $S_2$ and $S_3$". (It's too vague to be strictly wrong.) $S_2$ has a unique transitive subgroup, and $S_3$ has two so, using your comment, one might expect that there are two possibilities for $G$, namely $S_2\times S_3$ and $S_2 \times C_3$ but, as Derek pointed out, there is a third one, abstractly isomorphic to $S_3$ but where the involution acts "diagonally".

Comment: I would argue as follow: as you say, we know that $G$ embeds in $H:=S_2\times S_3$. Moreover, since $|G|$ is divisible by $3$, $G$ contains the unique Sylow $3$-subgroup $P$ of $H$. The quotient $H/P$ is isomorphic to the Klein group so, by the correspondence theorem, there are at most five possibilities for $G$. Moreover, $G$ must project surjectively on the first coordinate, which rules out two of those five, and we are done.